# Where is the mysql-test dir?

Tags: windows-10, mariadb

I have a mariadb (v.10.4.12) database, installed on Windows 10 .

As I need to write procedures, triggers, and grant permissions, I would like to write unit tests.

MariaDB and MySQL documentation speak about mysqltest, mysql_client_test, mysql-test-run.pl but I can't seem to find them anywhere near C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4.

So, where are they ? How can I run and test sql requests ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It is in the source package. or, it is in the github, and is there if you compile the server.
The test suite is huge, and end users do not need it, say in 99.999% cases. So it is not included, on Windows, as it would double the size of the package. If someone needs that, it is assumed he could compile the server from source.

mysql-test-run.pl is written primarily for people who work on server itself, and secondarily for those users who compile from source, to test the quality of their builds.

Comment: I see, it what i could understand but wasn't sure about. But how do people test a database and triggers / stored procedures ? [Well maybe it's a question to broad to write here]